# Apache не пишет error.log после очистки в PHPStorm

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, apache2.4

Apache не пишет error.log после очистки в PHPStorm 2016.3.2. Если очищаю в терминале `echo '' > error.log`, то нормально пишет и дальше. Права не меняются после очистки файла в PHPStorm. Перезапускаю Apache, ошибки пишет до первого сохранения файла логов в PHPStorm. И 777 права ставил - без толку. Что это может быть? ОС Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: что именно значит «очищаю в терминале» и «очиста файла в phpstorm»? где находится этот файл? каким образом он упомянут в конфигурации apache? от чьего имени apache обслуживает ваш сайт? кому принадлежит каталог, в котором находится файл? какие права у владельца, группы и всех остальных на этот каталог? дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос всей этой информацией, нажав [edit].

Comment: Не сохранять этот файл в PHPStorm. Судя по всему, в этот момент закрывается соответствующий дескриптор у апача.

Comment: В PHPStorm - ctrl+a, backspace, ctrl+s. Apache от www-data, файл находится рядом с папкой проекта. Сервер на ВиртуалБокс. Права на каталог логов `drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Дек 29 14:33 logs/` www-data и пользователь находятся в группе vboxsf

Comment: Etki, после сохранения лога в PHPStorm - запускается еще один процесс апача. Ну тогда буду пока из терминала очищать